# How to test third party library components with Detox in React-Native?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, detox

I have a example component code:

```
import { Button } from 'react-native-elements'
...

...
render() {
  return(
    <View>
      <Button testID='testButton' ... />
    </View>
  )
}
```

Example test file:

```
await element(by.id('testButton')).tap()
```

For a normal button, the tests work fine. For third party button, I'm Only using `react-native-elements`, The test fails and shows:

```
Error: Error performing 'single click' on view '(with tag value: is "testButton" and view has effective visibility=VISIBLE)'.
```

I have tried matching with the text of the button and it also failed and showed (`Add Product` being the buttons title/text):

```
Error: Error performing 'single click' on view '(with text: is "Add Product" and the view has effective visibility=VISIBLE)'.
```

Since the native buttons are passing I understand something needs to be done differently for third-party components. I have my own custom components and I have handled those by sending the `testID` deep down to the `react-native` components and they work. I can't figure out how to solve this case with third-party components.

I'm running it on Android

Comment: Unless the third party component allows you to pass the testID prop you won't be able to do it. However it does say that [Button](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/button.html) does take the props from `TouchableOpacity` / `TouchableNativeFeedBack` both of those have [TouchableWithoutFeedback](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablewithoutfeedback#props) props so it should be available

Comment: Sorry was away for a while but I see your point. `TouchableWithoutFeedback` takes a `testID` prop. Thanks. I'll try it out soon and try to post an answer/update here

Answer (score 0):

I guess I am a bit late, but for people who are facing this issue in the future like me, this problem is solvable by using a different matcher like "type". On iOS you can get the Button or TextInput via the native classname, so for example for the textinput you'd get it by doing

```js
await element(by.type('UITextField')).typeText('3102378979')
```